# Checking condition before initialising value in constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have an exercise in which I have to create a rectangle based on the opposite apexes (points). I have a class `Point` to initialise points and then I use them to create a rectangle (calculate width, height, area..).
I would like to check a condition if the x or y values of points aren't equal before initialising value in rectangle constructor. I tried to do it through the setter but am not sure how to pass it to the constructor. How to do it correctly - pass the value after checking the condition?

```
public class Point {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}


public class Rectangle {

    Point p1;
    Point p2;


    public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
    }
    public void setPoints() {
        boolean rectangleCondition = (p1.getX() != p2.getX()) && (p1.getY() != p2.getY());
        if(rectangleCondition) {
            Rectangle.p1 = p1;
            Rectangle.p2 = p2;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not put that validiation directly in your constructor?

Comment: @Eritrean I was told that I should avoid if statements in constructor.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. What I find good or beautiful is bad or ugly to someone another.IMHO if it is necessary you should add if/else statements to the constructor. On the contrary, I think it's bad practice to complicate your code in order just to avoid if-else.

Comment: It is usually best to keep methods as atomic (short and concise) and clearly defined as possible. This also applies to the constructor. You want the constructor to set up your object according to the parameters passed. And there is exactly where you should check whether the parameters are valid. And the easiest way to do this is with if-else. And if they are not valid, you throw an exception. To make a long story short: If you need an if/else, you can insert one. If necessary, you can also insert a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need the validation and thus your if-else outside the constructor then reverse it and call the setpoints method out of your constructor:

```
public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
    this.setPoints(p1,p2);
}

private void setPoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
    boolean rectangleCondition = (p1.getX() != p2.getX()) && (p1.getY() != p2.getY());
    if (rectangleCondition) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("x1/x2 y1/y2 shouldn't be equal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to do it in the constructor and let `p1` and `p2` as null object is the condition is not valid

```
public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
    if(p1.getX() != p2.getX() && p1.getY() != p2.getY()){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Or create default points :

```
public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
    if(p1.getX() != p2.getX() && p1.getY() != p2.getY()){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }else{
        this.p1 = new Point(0,0);
        this.p2 = new Point(1,1);
    }
}
```

Or throw an exception

```
public Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2) {
    if(p1.getX() != p2.getX() && p1.getY() != p2.getY()){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

---

Also remember that `Rectangle.p1` can't work, because the attributs are for each instance, calling an attribute like means it's global to the class, and it defined with `static` keyword

```
static Point globalPointForClass;
```